# Get parent div Id from .html inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a .html file contains ***iframe*** inside.

**Here is my code:**

```
<html>
   <div id="master">
      <iframe width="640" height="480" src ="xxxxx.html">
      #document
      <html>
         <head>
            <script>
               $(document).ready(function () {  
               var pDoc = document.getElementById("div1");
               var parentDiv = pDoc.parentNode;
               alert(parentDiv.id);
                });
            </script>
         </head>
         <body>
            <div id ="div1">
               <video id="myvideo1"> </video>
            </div>
         </body>
      </html>
      </iframe>
   </div>
</html>
```

what I want to do is, I want to get the parent div id which is `master` when I open this .html file.

I want to access the parent div id through .html in my frame. Please focus on my `<script>` tag. I want to show the alert of `parentDiv.id`.

So the expected output when I reload the page, the alert show `master`.
in below code, the alert is empty.

**Anyone know how to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

Apply Id to an iFrame (eg. `IFRAME_ID`)

```
$($("#IFRAME_ID").contents().document).find('#div1');
```

Comment: I tried, and this error comes:
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: the result only shows "[object Object]". The expected result that I want is "Master" which is the div above iframe tag